# Opening 3 divs based on whether checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the script below to show and hide a div based on whether or not the checkbox is checked, this if so I can show/hide a paypal button until they accept the terms.

But we now want of offer three payment option so it will need to open/close 3 divs, I tried just copying the div 3 times but it still only opened one. Can any body help me with this please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doInputs(obj){
  var checkboxs = obj.form.c1;
  var i =0, box;
  document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'none';
  while(box = checkboxs[i++]){
    if(!box.checked)continue;
    document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = '';
    break;
  }
}
</script>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="doInputs(this)">
</form>
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Also it would be amazing if someone could help me add in another `checkbox`, and make the paypal buttons (divs) only show when **BOTH** are `checked`?

Thanks very much!

Comment: There can be only one element with id "mydiv" on page. If you use multiple, then either modify their ID to be like "mydiv-1", "mydiv-2", "mydiv-3" or use class and query elements by class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also stole Marcus's answer but with the following improvements:

- I use the jQuery document ready event so the code fires after the page loads
- I simplified the logic
- It works for multiple types of payment

http://jsfiddle.net/5Byes/3/

Comment: @Marcus Recck, I guess that's the way it goes sometimes, have an up vote :)

Comment: @MarcusRecck - There's no accounting for the cowards that downvote without leaving any reason why.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can have an array or just two variables that are set to false. When a button is checked you set that equivalent value to the opposite of the current value (so if it was false, it would become true and vice-versa).

Here's a simple example of how you could accomplish this: http://jsfiddle.net/5Byes/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5Byes/4/

I stole Marcus' fiddle and updated it to do what you want.

Comment: Your select $("#PaymentOptions div") should be  $("#PaymentOptions>div") so that only the children divs are affected, not any div that is an ancestor

Answer (score 0):

Only one element with particular ID is allowed on the page. If you want more — use `class` attribute.
On the other hand, you could wrap all `div`s with payments method in one `div` with ID, let's say, `paymentsMethods` and then show/hide it.

```js
var paymentsDiv = document.getElementById('paymentsMethods');
if (box.checked) paymentsDiv.show(); else paymentsDiv.hide();
```

If you want 2 checkboxes — set `onclick` of both to same handler and change condition to `box1.checked && box2.checked`.

With jQuery (which is in your question tags) you could do `$('#paymentsMethods').toogle()` on checkbox click (see also `$.hide()` and `$.show()`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're looking for, you can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<input id="opt1cb" type="checkbox" value="Option 1" />Option 1<br />
<input id="opt2cb" type="checkbox" value="Option 2" />Option 2<br />
<input id="opt3cb" type="checkbox" value="Option 3" />Option 3<br />

<div class="option" id="opt1">Option 1</div>
<div class="option" id="opt2">Option 2</div>
<div class="option" id="opt3">Option 3</div>
<div class="option" id="opt23">Option 2 & 3</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.option').hide();

$('#opt1cb').click( function() {
    if( $(this).prop("checked") ) {
        $('#opt1').show();
    } else {
        $('#opt1').hide();
    }
});

$('#opt2cb').click( function() {
    if( $(this).prop("checked") ) {
        $('#opt2').show();
        if( $('#opt3cb').prop("checked") )
            $('#opt23').show();
    } else {
        $('#opt2').hide();
        $('#opt23').hide();
    }
});

$('#opt3cb').click( function() {
    if( $(this).prop("checked") ) {
        $('#opt3').show();
        if( $('#opt2cb').prop("checked") )
            $('#opt23').show();
    } else {
        $('#opt3').hide();
        $('#opt23').hide();
    }
});
```

​
Working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bCDqa/